# PercentRank Run-time error '1004' unable to get the PercentRank property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have been able to get this to work by making the range a static range, however even at that, I will eventually start getting the error message.  I am trying to do PercentRank on column "B", which is going to be a variable range.  For the sake of help, the number I'm using is 150.

```
Dim x As Double
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set relevant_array = ws.Range(ws.Range("B1"), ws.Range("B1").End(xlDown))
        x = WorksheetFunction.PercentRank(relevant_array, 150)
    MsgBox x
```

This file is massive, in column B there are roughly 260,000 rows of numbers.  Here's row 2-50, for example.

```
8.075
40.67
4.06
127.5
62.25
42.33333333
44.97
3.68
163.73
163.73
163.73
163.73
163.73
163.73
163.73
163.73
163.73
176.28
176.30
176.30
176.30
176.30
176.30
176.30
176.30
176.30
138.53
138.55
138.55
138.55
138.55
138.55
138.55
138.55
138.55
151.05
151.08
151.08
151.08
151.08
151.08
151.08
151.08
151.08
176.28
176.30
176.30
176.30
176.30
```

Comment: I'm able to replicate the issue when you specify the second parameter with a value that isn't part of the array. Are you sure that the value 150 is somewhere bounded in the array's min and max values?

Comment: @RyanWildry   Yes it is, I keep trying different number as well and keep getting the error

Comment: Are the values in the column numeric? Can you post what's in column B?

Comment: The column goes down a long way, about 260,000 rows.

Comment: @RyanWildry I've updated the post

Comment: Make sure you are selecting the correct range. Try printing out Debug.Print relevant_array.Address

Comment: @RyanWildry wildry Thanks for the suggestion.  I just did that to a message box and received '$B$1:$B$293663' so it appears as if it's doing the right range.

Comment: @cam Do you have multiple workbooks open?

Comment: @bwyn No, I do not

Comment: @RyanWildry  I figured out what the issue is.  I kept running the program with a bigger and bigger array until I got the error and then I went in the workbook and saw it was getting an error on a cell that had '0.00'.  How could I resolve this?

Comment: A value in the array had a value of 0.00 or the second parameter of the PercentRank function did?

Comment: @RyanWildry I feel so dumb.  There must have been a keystroke error when someone was putting in data, but there was a '=' about 20 rows down from the 0.00 that was the problem the entire time.  Again, thank you for your relentless help on this, Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the range with the following formula, getting the workbook by name, and multiplying all of the values in the range by 1 using paste special:

```
Set relevant_array = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
```